# Change Time Format in QGIS

Tags: qgis-plugins, fields-attributes, convert, time, format

How can i change time format from 0.377777 to normal time 9:00 in qgis is there any formula or anything. I tried the entire conversion in Excel with custom format h:mm but it takes me a lot of time to do that and joining the data back to gpkg file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `0.377777` is the time in days and you want to convert it in hours. So simply multiply it by 24:

`0.377777*24` returns `9.066647999999999`

You may want to round the result: `round (0.377777*24, 0)` rounds to whole numbers, thus the output is `9`.

Answer (score 2):

Open the attribute table for your data set, open the field calculator (the abacus icon). Make sure "add a new field" is checked. If the data are going to be updated, make a virtual field, if the data are static, just add a normal field. (to do this you probably have to enable editing on the data set) The field type should be set to Text (string).

Then you need to write a small python function. Press "Edit function" and edit the function so it reads:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *


@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom', referenced_columns=[])
def timeofday(time, feature, parent):
   time *= 24 # Converts from day to hours
   hours = int(time)
   minutes = (time*60) % 60
   seconds = (time*3600) % 60
   return("%d:%02d:%02d" % (hours, minutes, seconds))
```

[image]
I have QGIS in Norwegian, I hope this is understandable anyhow (there are different return statements in the screen shot and the text, use the one in the text to avoid timestamps like 8:4:3)

Press "Save and Load functions" and go to the Expression tab

type in in Expression

```
timeofday("fieldname")
```

where fieldname is the name of the field that holds your decimal time stamp and you should have the time correctly formatted in the new field.